# Is there a technical reason why most of desktop fans only have fixed speeds?

Tags: motor, power-electronics

The absolute majority of desktop fans only allow the choice of three speeds, leaving no option for the case when the lowest speed is still too fast. This is true even for expensive models that feature OLED displays, remote controls and other extras that seem much less required.

Is this just a design decision, or there is some technical reason that makes smooth speed adjustment difficult to implement?

Comment: Smooth speed adjustment is slightly more expensive to implement, and if it's generally not implemented, that probably means that the market is not willing to pay for it.

Comment: I was going to write something similar to @Dampmaskin. But with only a slight nuance: that is that manufacturers don't ***perceive*** sufficient buyers at the added price point. Manufacturers get it wrong, either way, plenty of times though. Some manufacturers perceive that there are buyers for the added features and find out later how wrong they are (and it costs them dearly.) Some manufacturers perceive there aren't enough buyers and are wrong, as well. But they don't find out as easily in this case. They only know when someone else takes the chance, markets the idea, and then succeeds.

Comment: Also, adding speed variation capability increases the number of things that can go wrong (decreases the MTBF), so the cost/benefit for the fan mfr is not there, unless market demand is so overwhelming that to NOT have speed variation results in selling no fans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes down to the costs and the type of motors used to drive the fans.

The simplest and cheapest way to drive a motor using mains power is with a basic AC motor. Unlike simple DC motors where rotational speed is determined by the voltage supplied the speed of an AC motor is dependent upon the frequency supplied. Multiple speeds can be achieved by switching in different sets of windings within the motor however it becomes impractical to include more than a few speeds in this way.

In order to give variable speed you would either need to change the frequency of the power supply or convert the power to DC and then drive the motor that way. Either way the cost of the electronics increases dramatically.

While fancier desk fans already include low power DC supplies and electronics for controls and displays that is all cheap off the shelf stuff. All of the high power parts used to drive the motor are still AC.

Answer (score -3):

The simple case fans from your desktop have stock speed. Some cases have built-in fan controller and a button where you set high/low speed of a case fan (this is not available on all desktop cases). 
The cooler that is set on your CPU can be adjustable, so if you want to set it on max speed or low (because you don't want to hear the noise, but your PC will become hotter) or automatic (when your PC need more cooling, you'll hear the cooler working faster).

Comment: From the question "Desktop  fan" seems to mean a mains powered fan that sits on your desk. Not a fan inside a desktop computer as you seem to be assuming.

Comment: Neat attempt for a first answer but missing the point. An AC powered desk fan != computer DC fan.

Comment: No, this is not about the CPU cooler